# Drupal user login fail in the chrome bowser

Tags: php, google-chrome, drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal. I have created 4 users and I activated those users in administration with dummy passwords. when i going to login in chrome browser. it doesn't show any thing and it says **"You are not authorized to access this page."**. and when i try to another browsers. it is successfully login. So how can i fix this  ? Sorry if any grammar mistakes.

[image]

Comment: Try clearing the cookies in your browser.

Comment: its working fine!  thanks @MilanG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, when that happens solution is to clear browser cookies.